# Invoke external shell script from PHP and get its process ID

Tags: php, external-process

How can I invoke an external shell script (Or alternatively an external PHP script) from PHP itself and get its process ID within the same script?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
$command =  'yourcommand' . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; ';

$pid = exec($command, $output);

var_dump($pid);
```

Comment: What's the meaning of " > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; "

Comment: it means 'send all the output to the null device, which means that all the output will be available in the stdout, and echo $! simply echo the pid, which is captured by the script

Comment: This also means that the command will run in the background (which would be what you want if you want the pid), and so your php script will not wait for the command to finish executing

Comment: this is useless when it doesn't wait for command to finish, -1 from me

Comment: If you want to wait for the command to finish remove & as & stands for asynchronous mode

Comment: @FlashThunder there are many scenarios where you want **not to wait** for the script to finish for example , you are providing an interface where you need to dump all 200K records to a CSV file and show the progress along with the export you would definitely want to run it in background and involve some table to calculate the current running export progress and update the progress bar in the frontend, So before you call a solution useless, please review all the use cases first.

Comment: @jimver04 I think technically the required modification would be to change `&` to `;`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to do this strictly using tools PHP gives you, rather than [Unix-specific wizardry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471320/1709587), you can do so with [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and [`proc_get_status`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php), although the need to pass a descriptor spec into `proc_open` makes it unpleasantly verbose to use:

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w']
];
$proc = proc_open('yourcommand', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$proc_details = proc_get_status($proc);
$pid = $proc_details['pid'];

echo $pid;
```

Comment: how do I get output?

Comment: `$pipes` will be filled with an array with a resource for each pipe in the `$descriptorspec`. So you need to read from the file descriptor `$pipes[1]` for stdout.

Answer (score 3):

For a cross-platform solution, check out [symfony/process](https://symfony.com/components/Process).

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
$process = new Process('sleep 100');
$process->start();
var_dump($process->getPid());
```

After you install `symfony/process` with composer (`composer require symfony/process`), you may need to update autoloading info with `composer dump-autoload` and then require the autoload with `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`.

Notice also that you can get PID of a *running* process only. Refer to [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for API details.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me is using `pgrep` to get the PID of the command (or process name) executed after calling `exec()` in PHP.

```
exec($command);
$pid = exec("pgrep $command");
```

This will work for launching background processes too. However, you must remember to pipe the program's output to `/dev/null` or else PHP will hang. Also, when calling `pgrep` you can't include the pipe portion of the command:

```
$command = "bg_process -o someOption";
exec($command + " > /dev/null &"); //Separate the pipe and '&' from the command
$pid = exec("pgrep $command");
```

Note that if the system has multiple processes launched with the same exact command, it will return the PIDs of all processes which match the command given to `pgrep`. If you only pass in a process name, it will return all PIDs with that process name.

Comment: This is more fragile than the other solutions given here for the reason you outline (if you have multiple processes invoked with the same command string, this doesn't let you tell which one is the one you just launched) and doesn't really provide any advantage over them to make up for it.