# How to check if there is a there is a wget instance running

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, wget

I have this php script that will run wget's fork processes each time this is called with the **&** :

```
wget http://myurl?id='.$insert_id .' -O ./images/'. $insert_id.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But how I can check if there is already a wget proces in progress and if there is one, don't run another one ?

Comment: You'll need the process ID: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471320/561309 then you can check if that process is still running or not

Comment: execute **ps -ef | grep wget** and find out. I have a lot longer and more legitimate solution if you need more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if process still running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111406/checking-if-process-still-running)

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to control running process (which in my case is php script).

Feel free to take out parts that you need and use them as you please.

```
class Process
{
  private $processName;
  private $pid;

  public $lastMsg;

  public function __construct($proc)
  { 
    $this->processName = $proc;
    $this->pid = 0;
    $this->lastMsg = "";
  }

  private function update()
  { 
    $output = array();
    $cmd = "ps aux | grep '$this->processName' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $2; }' | head -n 1";
    exec($cmd, $output, $rv);

    if ($rv == 0 && isset($output[0]) && $output[0] != "")
      $this->pid = $output[0];
    else
      $this->pid = false;

    return;
  }

  public function start()
  { 
    // if process isn't already running,
    if ( !$this->is_running() )
    { 
      // call exec to start php script
      $op = shell_exec("php $this->processName &> /dev/null & echo $!");

      // update pid
      $this->pid = $op;
      return $this->pid;
    }
    else
    { 
      $this->lastMsg = "$this->processName already running";
      return false;
    }
  }
  public function is_running()
  {
    $this->update();

    // if there is no process running
    if ($this->pid === false)
    {
      $this->lastMsg = "$this->processName is not running";
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->lastMsg = "$this->processName is running.";
      return true;
    }
  }

  public function stop()
  {
    $this->update();

    if ($this->pid === false)
    {
      return "not running";
    }
    else
    {
      exec('kill ' . $this->pid, $output, $exitCode);
      if ($exitCode > 0)
        return "cannot kill";
      else
        return true;
    }
  }

}
```