# Killing a process with PHP after exec()

Tags: php

```
<?php

$dira = dirname(__DIR__);

$output = exec($dira . "\\htdocs\\PocketMine-MP-stable\\start.cmd");

echo $output

?>
```

I need to find a way to kill the process after starting it with exec() this is for a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exec returns Once the process terminates. So after exec you cannot kill the process as it Is no longer running. You have to run the process with proc_open And you can then kill it with proc_terminate.

EDIT:
Actualy you can have exec return earlier if you redirect output of the command to a file And append `&` to the end of the command (or use nohup; Linux only maybe) so it runs in background. But getting the pid to send kill signal to it is only possible by name And that Is not very reliable

Answer (score -1):

You may use [posix_kill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php) to kill a process with identifier **pid**.

**Usage**

```
//...
exec($dira . "\\htdocs\\PocketMine-MP-stable\\start.cmd", $output);
$pid = (int)$output[0];
$killed = posix_kill(int $pid , int $sig);
```

> You should see all [signals and their codes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.constants.php) in your system using: kill
>   -l

Check my Repl [example](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/Killing-a-process-with-PHP-after-exec)

Comment: How do they get the pid?

Comment: "If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable."
check doc : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Not sure if the return status is the pid though.

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470910/invoke-external-shell-script-from-php-and-get-its-process-id) Aka, what's in this answer is probably not enough.

Comment: I gave it a try here https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/Killing-a-process-with-PHP-after-exec

Comment: Try adding `echo $pid.PHP_EOL;` and see what it is.

Comment: This Is nonsense. Even if you could get pid from exec, it would be invalidated when exec returns.

Comment: Actualy you can have it return earlier if you redirect output of the command to a file And append `&` to the end of the command (Linux only maybe) So it runs in background. Getting the pid tho, Is only possible by name And that Is not reliable.

Comment: `posix_kill` won't kill a process if it is originated from a browser request aka apache process.